# Java: Wait for function for up n seconds, if no complete re-try

Tags: java, multithreading, time, concurrency, icommand

**Background** (can skip to question below...)

Currently working with a lego Mindstorm robot and the icommand API (http://lejos.sourceforge.net/p_technologies/nxt/icommand/api/index.html).

Having some trouble with one of the motor control methods. The methods rotates the motor by a given angle:

```
Motor.A.rotateTo(target);
```

This function will not return until the motor has completed the movement. This is fine, but sometimes the motor fails to stop and will continue indefinitely thus stopping the program.

**Question**

Is there anyway I can make so the program waits for up *n* seconds for the method `Motor.A.rotateTo(target);`  to return. And then if it has not returned in that time, then call the method again. (If that could be looped until it is successful that would be even better.)

Thanks for reading, any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Joe

edit: corrected from `Motor.A.rotate(target);` to `Motor.A.rotateTo(target);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to stop a function's execution within a specified time in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183722/is-it-possible-to-stop-a-functions-execution-within-a-specified-time-in-java)

Comment: But won't stopping the method in the middle of execution cause an inconsistent state in the object?

Comment: @Tudor Ah yeh, yeh it would. I meant write `Motor.A.rotateTo(target);` sorry my mistake! The motors have tacho-counters which record how far they have turned (positive clockwise, negative anti-clockwise , 1 tacho = 1 degree). So i can simply re-call that method and it will rotate until it reaches the target tacho-count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExecutorService` or other threading solution to run `rotate` in a separate thread and wait for results. Here is a complete program that also retries given number of times:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException {
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    runWithRetry(pool, 5);  //run here
}

public static void runWithRetry(final ExecutorService pool, final int retries) throws TimeoutException {
        final Future<?> result = pool.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Motor.A.rotate(angle);
            }
        });
        try {
            result.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  //wait here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            if (retries > 1) {
                runWithRetry(pool, retries - 1);  //retry here
            } else {
                throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `Motor#rotate(long count, boolean returnNow)` ? You can then call `stop()` if you want the motor to stop after a specific time.

```
Motor.A.rotate(150, true);
Thread.sleep(3000);
Motor.A.stop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had considered this but how do know if the motor completed the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

What about something along the lines of :

```
int desiredPosition = Motor.A.getTachoCount() + ANGLE_TO_TURN;
long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis + MAX_TIME_OUT;
Motor.A.forward();
while (timeout>System.currentTimeMillis && desiredPosition>Motor.A.getTachoCount()); //wait for the motor to reach the desired angle or the timeout to occur
Motor.A.stop();
```